# Extract live data from Microsoft SQL database in JSON format

Tags: php, json, database, sql-server-2008, extract

I was just given this project at work. I think I can get the data, but not the live data. I figure that it is fairly easy to format it into JSON by exporting the SQL data to an excel file, then use open resources to transform that xml data into JSON. However I have no idea how to extract the live data, other than having it constantly run in the terminal. My supervisor said possibly PHP, but I have no idea if this would work since I have absolutely zero familiarity with PHP. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: If you want live data you'll either have to go with long-polling or websockets, both of which are something you can do with PHP or any number of web back-end languages. You don't need a middle-man, like Excel, because PHP can take the data coming from the database and convert it to JSON on the fly. You can use other languages too.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I'll check out long polling and websockets